Problem with numpy: pip install numpy "Requirement already satisfied: numpy"
when working with numpy I have found this problem, that submodules or packages installed in a virtual environment don't recognize the numpy.
(venv) D:\felipe\work\ml\mnist>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\felipe\work\ml\mnist\venv\lib\site-packages (2.0.0)

the problem is caused by a new and incompatible version of numpy apparently

Hi @FreePalestine, no it doesn't answer my question. people usually search error messages I don't see the other question to have my specific error message anywhere, but I fail to see how I could possibly convince you that my Stable Diffusion problem is DIFFERENT from the other dude's OPENCV problem, but I guess if you want to close the question go ahead, I fail to see how that will affect anything, somebody else will just have the same problem, and they won't have the answer here, and we have to be fine with that.

brother, I did not close your question. Someone else did.

apologies @FreePalestine but whoever closed it isn't getting it. we need error messages in the title, otherwise people won't find the content. how do I reopen?

I think you need 3k rep and 4 other people to reopen it.

That's useful information @FreePalestine thanks for taking the time to answer, I'll check back in 2032 when I have the rep and the bug is irrelevant. I honestly didn't expect this much drama

I wish I could help.

controversially, I decided to install a version of numpy of the 1.x branch.
This has fortunately solved the problem for me.
I figured I should share because I suspect a lot of people will have this problem.
pip install numpy==1.26.4

this is because the numpy team is trying to make things better and they decided to make incompatible changes.
I had this problem using both Stable Diffusion 3 and also using a simple MNIST tutorial on matplotlib, so a LOT of packages may break.
Hopefully the situation will be resolved shortly by a lot of package maintainers, but I suspect it may take years for all the code to be updated, for the major packages, creating a schism in the ecosystem.
